# How to prevent tech providing companies from down-voting SO questions that reveal defects in their products or services?

Tags: support, down-votes, etiquette, behavior

Theoretically, technology companies can have employees systematically down-vote all questions that indirectly reveal their products' or services' defects knowing that this would help hide the questions and ultimately prevent the users from posting further questions on Stack Overflow. (Due to the SO banishment algorithm.)

It may have happened to me lately. Of course, I do not have access to the proper data that would allow me to prove this, but recent events made me suspect something along those lines.

Is there a mechanism in place to avoid such situations? That btw. would be impossible to be proven by the "victims" alone!

Comment: Bold accusations there. Got any evidence?

Comment: *How do i know it was them ?... They use the same username here as the one they use as Telerik's support ppl*. This makes no sense. You can't see the usernames associated with votes, unless you work for SE.

Comment: Well the [answering part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841247/where-is-the-info-on-how-to-use-kendos-upload-ui-feature) checks out -- both users that answered this question have their employment status in their profile.  But that doesn't say anything about votes. It is just as possible that someone downvoted your question if they came across it and believed that you hadn't put any effort into it, or any other arbitrary voting reason.

Comment: If your question isn't uniquely applicable to Telerik, and you won't provide any evidence, consider removing your slander. Ask a general question.

Comment: Making the presumption that it's those people downvoting your questions is simply irresponsible, and stating so publicly without any evidence to support your accusation is wrong. You're posting slanderous accusations with no evidence to support them.

Comment: I just did added comments about that !!!???

Comment: Ok, I've read your [most recent downvoted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841247/where-is-the-info-on-how-to-use-kendos-upload-ui-feature). It deserves downvotes, maybe not three, but some. You've adopted an aggressive stance, probably in response to what you perceive as inadequate documentation. That should really get scrubbed from your question. And all you're really looking for a pointer to documentation, which makes your question off-topic, but which was generously provided by two Telerik employees.

Comment: Alright, alright i give up...

Comment: As I said, you've posted unfounded accusations **without evidence**. Your assumption that it was those individuals that downvoted you does not make it fact; nor does the fact that they posted **answers** to your question. **Evidence** is actual proof that they were the ones that downvoted, and unless they actually left a comment saying they did so you simply have to way to obtain that evidence.

Comment: I admit i sometimes got super pis***ed at them for not providing support despite the fact that we are paying customers and it might have been visible through my questions here... Should i be blocked for this ??... Seriously ?....

Comment: The question ban is intended to detect and block users who repeatedly post questions of poor quality. Rants included. Don't post rants. If you suspect malfeasance, that's one thing, but it doesn't look like that's what's happened here.

Comment: Had I of found that question naturally I would certainly have downvoted and flagged to close for assorted reasons (mostly recommend an off site resource). It seems highly likely this happened, even if it was the telerik guysit was a legitimate downvote

Comment: @Tuthmosis without evidence, all you have a accusations and potential for liable (since you've made unfound accusations in writing).  I've found the SO community to respond very unfavorably when a company tries to game the system for their own benefit, so if it were true, it would not be good for them, but you need to bring some strong evidence than some downvotes...

Comment: @Tuthmosis ....unfortunately your post history is not stellar, you had numerous posts with no score or a few downvotes.  If they really were doing this, there would be more of a pattern than just 1 person.

Comment: I understand Richard, the thing is that their support desk can require multiple weeks to provide valid answer to any question no matter how simple... They themselves recommend to use StackOverflow as an alternative. Every client soon realize that the same questions get answered on SO in just a few minutes... so yes perhaps are we asking stuff that shouldn't be asked on SO... Sorry... It's a reflex of asking here.

Comment: Don't vent your customer/commercial issues here. Do it in other venues.

Comment: Can we all simmer-down and have a good laugh about this ridiculous storm?

Comment: Canada! Thats ages away! You were lucky this time. But seriously you did make some pretty heavy claims

Comment: Re your updated question;  if you suspect something then flag!

Comment: I did flagged my original question but no results yet. Telerik confirmed by email today that i was right from the start !... The original SO question should not be deleted and deserves to get the proper answer as other ppl will face the same situation i went through during the past few days !

Comment: That you were 'right' about their documentation has nothing at all to do with whether your question was appropriate here, or that what you are asking about here happens at all.

Answer (score 28):

1. You don't have access to the detailed voting history for your question, and therefore you don't actually know that it is Telerik employees that are downvoting your question.  It wouldn't make much sense for them to downvote your questions specifically.  It is their product, after all.
2. Your latest question is "Where is the docs?" which is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow.  That it attracted downvotes is not surprising, given that it is off-topic.

I think it is more likely that you are being downvoted for question quality, not specifically targeted by Telerik employees.

Comment: I would add that the most recent question also seemed to be partly used as complaint about kendo, stack overflow is not the place for that

Comment: @Richard, since the storm above was pretty much caused by the "recent question" you are refering to, note that i just updated it. I removed the "unholy" references to the "insufficient documentation" and replaced it with "How to use the component..." Also, note that none of the Telerik's proposed answers are working !!! I was damn right from the very start, it's a relatively new component they offer and it is definitely not working properly in addition of being poorly documented. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841247/how-to-use-kendos-upload-ui-feature

Comment: @tuthmosis I think trading standards (or the canadian equivalent) are the people to talk to about that, we have literally zero power to uphold a complaint against a random company.

Answer (score 10):

A Telerik employee here. I just want to note that Telerik employees answer SO questions mostly in their free time (this is not part of our job). We respect and value SO rules and "revenge downvoting" is pointless in our point of view.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much, accusations about voting regularities are made regularly (I have been a victim myself), are almost always wrong and are never taken seriously without considerable evidence. Which is why people should flag if they have concerns not ‘call people out’ on meta.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why my original question still has negative votes !?... And most of all, why it got deleted ???... It was updated to fit the rules and is extremely relevant as it proves by A+B that there is a bug with Kendo upload component ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841247/how-to-use-kendos-upload-ui-feature

Comment: @Tuthmosis I can't see the deleted question but setting out to *prove* something is probably the problem

Comment: What do you mean by setting out to prove ?

Comment: you can't access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841247/how-to-use-kendos-upload-ui-feature ?

Comment: @Tuthmosis you said it was "extremely relevant as it proved that there is a bug with Kendo upload component". True or otherwise proving things are buggy (except your own code) isnt what SO is for. And no, only users with > 10k reputation can see deleted questions

Comment: I just want to reach those ppl successfully using the problematic component... i suspect there are some out there. If they do use the component, it means that they were able to find a workaround for this bug... This is why i use SO... Now is there a problem there too ?

Comment: Side note to korchev; we appreciate the support and information you provide here, by the way!